# Derivation of velocities in the Coriolis force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, approximations, coriolis-effect

In [Fitzpatrick's *Newtonian Dynamics* book](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/) on the [Coriolis force](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node58.html), he states

> \begin{align}
> v_{x'}&\simeq V_0\cos\theta-2\Omega t V_0\sin\lambda~\sin\theta   \tag{433}\\
> v_{y'}&\simeq-V_0\sin\theta-2\Omega t V_0\sin\lambda~\cos\theta   \tag{434}
> \end{align}
>   To lowest order in $\Omega$, the above equations are equivalent to
>   \begin{align}
> v_{x'}&\simeq V_0\cos\left(\theta+2\Omega t\sin\lambda  \right)\tag{435}\\
> v_{y'}&\simeq -V_0\sin\left(\theta+2\Omega t\sin\lambda  \right)\tag{436}
> \end{align}

I simply don't get how the above equations are equivalent. In fact, if I take a magnitude (of the total vector) they are different. I also don't understand what "To lowest order in $\Omega$" means here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Fitzpatrick states towards the beginning,

> The following solution method exploits the fact that the Coriolis force is much smaller in magnitude that the force of gravity: hence, $\Omega$ can be treated as a *small* parameter

Generally, when statements like that are made, powers (greater than 1) of the term in question are considered to be zero:
$$
\Omega\ll1; \quad \Omega^n\,\approx0\,\,\forall\,\,n>1
$$
Thus,
$$
a\Omega+b\Omega^2\approx a\Omega
$$
for small $\Omega$.

In the [small angle approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation), we have
\begin{align}
\sin\theta&\approx\theta\\
\cos\theta&\approx1-\frac{\theta^2}2\\
\tan\theta&\approx\theta
\end{align}
We can apply this to your first $v_{x'}$ equation:
\begin{align}
v_{x'}&\approx V_0\left(\cos\theta-2\Omega\sin\lambda \sin\theta t\right)\\
&\approx V_0\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}2-2\Omega\sin\lambda\theta t\right)
\end{align}
You can then [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) to finish the solution, ignore the $\Omega^2$ term and end up with Equation (435) that the author gives.

Comment: I've completed the square and get $Vo((1-\Omega\theta sin\lambda t )^2 -\frac{\theta^2}{2})$ I cant come up with the final equation, hehe.

Comment: You should only be considering the terms with respect to $\theta$, so complete the square with $\theta^2/2+2\Omega\sin\lambda\theta t$.

Comment: Wow. I'm just impressed. Is this a famous derivation or something? When does this stop being valid? How much time has to pass? Thanks.

Comment: Famous? Probably not, I cheated and expanded (435) and recognized the difference between the two relations as a completing the square :). It stops being a valid relation when the second term is no longer small (either $\Omega\approx1$ or $t$ being some nominal value).

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, Richard Fitzpatrick.  Great guy.
Ok, If you start with the second set of expressions, use the appropriate double-angle-formula and then assume the "angle" $2\Omega \sin\lambda t$ is small  (note that the $t$ is not within the sin function!), you get the first expressions, e.g.

$$\cos(\theta+\phi)  = \cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta\sin\phi,$$
and then for small $\phi$, use the first-order terms in the Taylor expansion for the trig functions, i.e. $\cos\phi \simeq 1$, and $\sin\phi\simeq \phi$.
In your case, $\phi = 2\Omega\sin\lambda t$, where again the $t$ is intended as a (linear) multiplicative factor and not inside the $\sin$ function.

Similarly, $$\sin(\theta+\phi) = \sin\theta\cos\phi + \cos\theta\sin\phi,$$
and you can take if from there...;-)

Woops, looks like Kyle beat me to the punch while I was typing this in!

Comment: Out of curiosity, could Fitzpatrick's books become non-free any time? They are too good. I guess I'll download them for fear of this. Hehe.